# move pr2 with ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I want to pr2 program that move pr2 ros in left and right
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49438/move-pr2-with-ros/) by [light86](https://answers.ros.org/users/3692/light86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Move left:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /base_controller/command geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.1, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

Move right:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /base_controller/command geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: -0.1, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1